# Is there any information on the lifespan of SARS-CoV-2 antibodies?

Tags: covid-19, sars-cov-2, antibodies

Like all cells, antibodies die off after a period of time. A human body may (or not) be able to efficiently replace or replicate these antibodies. Whether the original antibodies were generated naturally (by sickness) or artificially (by immunization), an essential question might be, What is the lifespan of antibodies specific to SARS-CoV-2?

It is likely that because of the novelty of SAR-CoV-2, the medical community has not yet had sufficient time to study this question, however past studies on Coronavirus types should be available.

(for example [MERS antibody](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4880093/) studied MERS antibody longevity. I don't know if that provides any clues regarding SARS-CoV-2. I look to members at this site for guidance)

Comment: I think you should instead focus only on the last sentence of your question, and ask about SARS for example, or MERS, or another specific coronavirus, and not SARS-CoV-2. The answer is going to be totally different for different coronaviruses which is why there is so much hedging on "we don't know yet" with regards to antibodies and immunity with sars-cov-2. See also https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1169/should-questions-that-people-suspect-currently-have-no-answer-be-closed-or-left

Comment: @BryanKrause I acknowledge that prior studies on other related virus may not be immediately transferable to SARS-CoV-2, however as a matter of medical history, prior studies help to inform and act as a starting point to solve novel - but related - problems. The lifespan of antibodies to fight Covid-19 is relevant today and should be of great interest.

Comment: @BryanKrause in reference to your link which seems to address 'should we close  questions we suspect has no literature answer' -  I'm not a medical professional and certainly not a professional medical researcher so my proficiency at locating medical research papers is limited. That is not to say that I did no research at all, rather what I found were studies that were done on other related virus antibody life span. I am hopeful that the participants at this site might be more talented than I, and/or are more knowledgeable might be able to expand on the subject.

Comment: My point in linking that is that you acknowledge that this simply cannot be known yet because the virus is so new; it's not even possible for someone to have had antibodies more than a few months.